# How to dynamically end a loading animation

Tags: javascript, loops, animation, loading, after-effects

I would like to create a loading animation (not in CSS, it is a complex Adobe After Effects animation). My goal is to create an animation that constantly loops and whenever the loading should stop, the animation finishes with something different. For example, say a circle constantly spins around, when `animation.stop()` is called, the circle should spin super fast and scale down until it is gone. So the animation has a `dynamic ending` whenever `animation.stop()` is called. How would I go about this?

My first thought was to create two animations. The looping animation and the end animation. As soon as `animation.stop()` is called, you queue the end animation. So the loop animation will finish its last loop and then play the end animation. Is this worth a shot? How do you `queue` animations in HTML/Javascript?

What you can't do is just stop/hide the looping animation and start/show the end animation, because the looping animation has to end its cycle otherwise it won't look smooth. My actual loop animation is more complex than the circle example above. So we need to end its loop so that it transitions nicely into the end animation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to be answering your question but i have to assume you have knowledge of Jquery, i had this challenge a while ago, but i figured out that due to the limitations of javascript, you might have to create two animations as you said.. and note your animations have to be exported as animated GIFs, else using a video or any advanced graphics is going to be cumbersome or heavy.

The looping animation and the end animation. now the trick is to load both of them together, but to hide one and display the other when the event is triggered...

Both animations have the same properties, basically dimensions and position. 
so when loading is in progress - you make the looping animation visible and hide the end animation. then, when the loading ends - you make the end animation visible and hide the looping animation. and the last part is to slowly kill the end animation as it plays to the end.. - you use a javascript setTimeout, or setInterval, because you cannot add events to the frames of your animation, but you can time it and pass an event when the time is due..

using jquery this is what i'd do.

lets say you have two div-tags with the GIF images in them.. positioned anywhere on the page.

```html
 // loopDiv - loop_animation.gif
 <div id="loopDiv"> <img src="images/animations/loop_animation.gif"/> </div>

 // endDiv - end_animation.gif, - and this plays for 6 seconds. 
 <div id="endDiv"> <img src="/images/animations/end_animation.gif"/> </div>
```

//when the loading is in progress

```
var endt = 20000; //20seconds 20 * 1000 milliseconds. 

function doProgress(){
   clearInterval(endt);  //always clear the interval before starting.
   $('#loopDiv').show();
   $('#endDiv').hide();
}

function endProgress(){
   $('#loopDiv').hide();
   $('#endDiv').show();
   setInterval(function(){
       $('#endDiv').hide();
    }, endt);  //hide the div after 20seconds 
}
```

if you get that correctly this should work, but if you want an advanced solution, you can use [CreateJs - EaselJs library](https://createjs.com/)  and utilize the canvas API. using the canvas API, you can simulate complex animation with inbound events alongside..

i hope i answered you correctly. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple example i think it will help you, no libraries just JS/CSS.

```js
function changeAnimation() {
   var loader = document.getElementById("brnx-loading");
 
   loader.classList.remove('brnx-loading-slow');
   loader.classList.add('brnx-loading-fast', 'brnx-loading-scaleout');
}
```

```css
.brnx-loading {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  overflow: show;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  font: 0/0 a;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
 /* visibility: hidden; */
}

/* Transparent Overlay */
.brnx-overlay {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.brnx-loading:after {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: -25px;
 
  content: '';
  display: block;

  border-left: 6px solid rgba(60, 167, 115, .15);
  border-right: 6px solid rgba(60, 167, 115, .15);
  border-bottom: 6px solid rgba(60, 167, 115, .15);
  border-top: 6px solid rgba(60, 167, 115, .8);
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.brnx-loading-slow:after {
  animation: rotation 1200ms infinite linear;  
}


.brnx-loading-fast:after {
  animation: rotation 300ms infinite linear;  
}

.brnx-loading-scaleout  {
  transform: scale(0);
  animation: scaleout 1000ms ease-in;  
}
 

/* Animation */
@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}


@keyframes scaleout {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    
  <div class="brnx-overlay"  onclick="changeAnimation()">
    
      <div id="brnx-loading"         
      class="brnx-loading brnx-loading-slow"></div>
    
    </div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, i am just changing the class to speed up the animation and add the scale out effect.
Click on the output tab to start the scaleout animation.